# Transfer AWS to own infrastructure

Tags: amazon-web-services

Our company wants to use AWS services, but is worried about the future. What happens when Amazon discontinues a service, what if prices rise too much, what if a customer wants to move the services from the cloud to his own infrastructure?

Is it possible to move all services to an own network? Only some? Which ones? How much effort is it?

Edit to clarify: Some of our customers have huge intranets (banking, automotive, ..) and people to take care of the server maintenance. For privacy reasons they want to keep all customer data under their own control.

Our idea is to happily develop stuff on the AWS cloud, but then the final deployment would be to the customers infrastructure.

The question is mostly about the effort. Is there a button to export the service, are there standard procedures one could follow to achieve it, or is everything trial and error until you get the same results? Is the software used for the AWS services generally available for installation on own hardware, and so on.

Ideally there is a list somewhere out there, telling us which software is used in which service, what is needed to move it. Usually the applications we covering only a small part of the customers business, so there won't be any performance problems. We can assume a single high end machine could be enough for one customer.

Comment: Short answer: Is it possible? Yes.  Amazon is not magic.  How much effort is it? It depends on how well you plan.  Use industry standard interfaces exclusively, and it will be easier.  Use tools portable between AWS and open solutions, and it will be much easier.

Comment: If you use a configuration management to configure your services with the ec2 intances, you can easily migrate.

Comment: Use operating systems generally available - Ubuntu / Centos over Amazon Linux. Set up your systems using open standard infrastructure as code - puppet, chef, Teraform. You could put an abstraction layer / central point in your code for calling AWS services (eg SQS "enqueue this"), but that takes effort and you can just change your code later. Ensure you use open data formats and such, so you can export all your data - which IMHO you should back up outside the AWS cloud regularly in a way it can't be deleted by anyone who manages to compromise your AWS resources so they can't delete backups.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is impossible to answer because it completely depends on how you use and leverage the resources available from the cloud provider.

When you arguably don't make very good use of Amazon as a cloud provider (for instance when you **only deploy virtual server instances** and then as a "classic sysadmin" install and configure your own services on those VPS's and/or have that automated) you can relatively easily move/recreate those VPS's and your services on a new on-premise infrastructure or with a different cloud provider.

When you do **use cloud services properly** you and your developers leverage the knowledge and effort of 1000's of Amazon engineers and you don't have install and manage your own VPS's with load-balancers, databases, NoSQL clusters etc, you simply **leverage more or less completely managed services** for all of that, which will scale effortlessly based on your usage. You will only need to focus on the area's where your company really adds value.

To then move away from the cloud you'll need to **invest up front** a lot of time/money/effort **to build up your own replacement infrastructure and services** before you can migrate away. (You don't necessarily need to invest up front in buying hardware, you can easily lease hardware, but the real cost will be in configuring all the services you'll need to replace.)   The risk you also have is that your engineers aren't better than Amazon's at building and maintaining your *complete stack*. It is quite different to leverage existing services as building blocks compared to making those from scratch and maintaining them.

After your own infrastructure has been build up it will still need to be maintained. Consider what sizing your infrastructure up will cost and if sizing down would be possible (as that is often difficult to do with your own hardware.)

Comment: thank you for your explanation! will add more details to the question to clarify.